# Django ManyToMany relation contains value

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, relationship, django-orm

I'm trying to search through a ManyToMany relationship, but I'm doing something wrong and I'm not sure about what it is

```
t = Teacher.objects.get(username=u.username)
var = list(Allowed.objects.filter(allowed=t))
```

This is the class I'm using:

```
class Allowed(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, related_name='allowed_teacher')
  reason = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
  allowed = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher, related_name='who_is_allowed', blank=True, null=True)
```

How can I do it?

**EDIT:**
`Teacher` doesn't have any reference to Allowed

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking with that answer :) What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error, not getting the results you expect? Also, did you check that there are values in your `allowed` field?

Comment: That's possibly the problem, but when I changed the code, adding 'if Allowed.objects.filter(allowed=t).exists():' I got an error like this: 'no such column: quizzer_allowed_allowed.teacher_id'

Comment: Then it sounds like you may need to run a `syncdb`

Comment: Solved, South forgot to create one field in the schema migration

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do:

```
t = Teacher.objects.get(username=u.username)
var = t.allowed_set.all()
```